# JavaScript syntax check with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eval, syntax-checking

How could a Commando like me check if inputed code is a valid JavaScript source using some JavaScript built-in methods (if any!) or in any other possible way!? (Something like a preparser found in various IDE's like NetBeans, Eclipse, etc)?

I have to check if code is OKAY and then window.eval()-it to the current document instance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Okay'? whether the code should have correct syntax or should be following coding standards or should not contain malicious code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lint library like:

http://www.javascriptlint.com/download.htm

EDIT:

Sorry, that's a compiled linter and you're wanting something for on-the-fly. Try jslint: http://jslint.com

Comment: how could I include jslint in my current script(s)?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I mis-understood. You're wanting to do this in javascript on the fly, right?

Comment: The library you linked is not written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your need is to check whether the code will not throw any syntax errors, following is my solution:

```
var code = "asdfsd = 1";

try {
    (function(){
        new Function(code);
    })()
}
catch(e) {
    alert('error');
}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5NpGa/

Comment: `new Function(string)` is `eval` in disguise.

Comment: They have their differences. For example, `new Function(str)` doesnt affect the variables in the scope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/is-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing

Comment: Moreover from what i understood, his need was to check if a code will work, not whether it is following coding practices.

Comment: From the OP: _"I have to check if code is OKAY and then window.eval()-it"_.

Comment: Be aware that the `catch` in the proposed solution is going to be triggered only in the case of runtime errors (e.g. variable `asdfsd` is not defined). But that code is still syntactically valid. `asdfsd = 1 1` (note the space between the 1s) is not going to be catched.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for Crockford's [jslint.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint). It's the same code that powers http://jslint.com/.