# Getting function through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was wondering how I can get a function from an AJAX request, like this:

Let's say I have a file called myfunction.js, that looks like this:

```
function(bar){
 alert(bar);
}
```

Can I retrieve it via Ajax as a function, like this?

```
var foo = $.ajax({url:'myfunction.js',async:false}).responseText;
```

And run it like this?

```
foo(bar);
```

The reason I ask is because I know `responseText` is a string,
so I'm not really sure if JavaScript will understand that it is a function.

Is there a way to convert a string into a function?

Comment: jQuery has a `getScript` method you can use to load external scripts and fire a callback function once available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to beware.

Chrome and IE don't allow you to eval an anonymous function directly (FF is fine). That is

```
// Throws Syntax Error in Chrome, Object expected in IE 8
var fun = eval('function(){return 5}'); fun();
```

A hackaround is to put it in an array, doesn't seem very reliable for the future:

```
var fun = eval('[function (){return 5}][0]'); fun();
```

The only safe way would be to make sure your functions are named, since the following works fine in all browsers:

```
eval('function a(){return 5}]'); a(0);
```

See [Are eval() and new Function() the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/is-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing) for further discussion

Comment: I think it's pretty awesome when the chosen answer gets 0 votes, there should be a badge for that!

Answer (score 3):

In your JS file, give the function a name.

```
function foo(bar){
   alert(bar);
}
```

Then use [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load it.

```
$.getScript('myfunction.js', function(){
   foo('test');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely:

```
foo = eval('(' + foo + ')');

foo(bar);
```

You could use `new Function` but in my testing it doesn't work on some versions of IE.

Comment: Be careful! eval'ing a function doesn't work in some versions of IE. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/is-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing/4599932#4599932 A workaround at the time I answered that question was to use `eval('[function a(){return 5}][0] ')`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using new Function instead of eval, eval executes the code as soon as it's parsed, which is not what I was after.

This is what I ended up doing, and it works very nicely in firefox, chrome, and IE 7+ (no errors at all)

```
function createMyFunction(code){return new Function('params',code)};

var thecode = $.ajax({
                  url:      'myCode.js',
                  async:     false,
                  dataType: 'html'

               }).responseText

myFunction = createMyFunction(thecode);
```

I know the createMyFunction is pretty lazy in terms of not being able to define different arguments, but using a single params map works for my templating scenario quite well.

Note the `dataType:'html'` in the ajax request, if you don't specify a plain text mime type, jQuery will actually recognize that you are getting JS code and try to parse it, which generally ends up throwing a parse error or sometimes "Uncaught TypeError: params is not defined".

With this, I am able to have template files that specify template-specific events, and keep them organized in the same way as the markup and css files for that template.

Thanks for the help everyone, the reason I chose the answer that I did is because the link at the end pointed me in the right direction.

Cheers,
D

Comment: The Function constructor is new to me. I find it extremely useful  I cant wait to use it :) thanx!