# How to pass a JS function to frontend as JSON property in JSF?

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to pass a Javascript function as the JSONObject element in primefaces.

In my Java backing bean, I have:

```
JSONObject serie = new JSONObject();
serie.put("name", "Single data serie");
...
serie.put( <other JSON fields and objects> )
...
serie.put("method", "function() { return '1'; }");
```

Then I send the object **serie** to frontend and use that JSONObject in my Javascript. Everyting works fine, except that "method" is being considered as String, not as function.

**Is there any way to send the function as function, not String?**

I use the

```
org.primefaces.json.JSONObject
```

class. I know, that there is also the class

```
org.json.JSONObject
```

but it seems to me as the same.

Regards,

Mateusz

Comment: Ok, I worked it out as described here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854094/java-add-function-to-json-object-without-using-quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854094/java-add-function-to-json-object-without-using-quotes)

I implemented the JSFunction class, that implements the JSONString interface and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like bad design, but you're probably looking for [`eval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp);

Some code sample:

```
eval("function x() { return '1'; } x();");
```

prints `"1"`.

Comment: Hi. Are you sure, that this will work with the json property? I see here only a replacement of the JSON property value from:

`"method": "function() { ...}"`
to

    `"method": "eval(\"function....\")"`

Literally both properties are Strings.
Regards,

Comment: Hi again. I worked it out, see my comment to the original question.