# Node "ReferenceError: require is not defined" when executing a Function object

Tags: node.js, function, require

I'm trying to execute a Function object which is essentially the same as the following pseudo-code:

```
var testF = new Function("x","y", "var http = require('http');");
testF('foo','bar');
```

And get:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Do I need to somehow add something that reloads the require module as it's not a global module in Node? If so, google has not been my friend so any pointers on how to do so would be fantastic.

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since [new Function is a form of eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/are-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing) you can just `eval` it:

```
eval("function testF(x,y){ console.log(require);}");
testF(1,2);
```

If you want to follow the original approach you'll need to pass those **globals** to the function scope:

```
var testF = new Function(
  'exports',
  'require',
  'module',
  '__filename',
  '__dirname',
  "return function(x,y){console.log(x+y);console.log(require);}"
  )(exports,require,module,__filename,__dirname);

testF(1,2);
```

Comment: I was hoping not to use eval and so I'm going to refactor using another technique to dynamically generate functions. Your very helpful answer helped to point me in another direction

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution, using the same method of calling the Function constructor:

```
var testF = new Function("x","y", "var require = global.require || global.process.mainModule.constructor._load; var http = require('http');");
testF('foo','bar');
```

Comment: Thank you, this let me find a security hole in our API server.