# Executing JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wonder how the JS on this site is executed when you click on "run":

http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#3

It's not like JSFiddle, so he didn't use IFrames.

I searched the web and found [reptl.it](http://repl.it/), that executes code too. I don't know if it works the same way. Can please someone explain the magic?

Comment: You can do something like: `var script = document.createElement('script');  script.text = '<your JS code>';  document.head.appendChild(script);`.

Comment: Study the "Run" button in developer mode. You can see all the magic.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code, they just create a function containing the code in the textarea, using the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Syntax) which takes the function body as a method. Then they call the function:

```
try {
    (new Function( jQuery("#code").val() ))();
} catch(e){
    error(e.message);
}
```

This works in a very similar way to `eval` with the exception that the new function cannot access variables in the current scope, as the Note in the link states:

> **Note:** Functions created with the Function constructor do not create closures to their creation contexts; they always are created in the global scope. When running them, they will only be able to access their own local variables and global ones, not the ones from the scope in which the Function constructor was called. This is different from using eval with code for a function expression.

Comment: doh, I spent too long on my 2nd paragraph :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe :) i know the feeling

Comment: Thank you! :) So it's like `eval`?

Comment: @gform not entirely - see the note in the linked page

Comment: @gform The differences are also covered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/are-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing)

Answer (score 2):

When you click `run`, it's submitting a `<form>` that contains the code.  The form submit however is handled in javascript, with the below code handling the running of the entered script:

```
try {
    (new Function( jQuery("#code").val() ))();
} catch(e){
    error(e.message);
}
```

In essence, it's creating a new function using the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) and immediately running it.  The `assert`, `log` and `error` functions are normal functions defined elsewhere on the page.  Any errors are caught with the catch and passed off to the same `error` function.

Comment: Thank you, didn't thought it was so simple.