# Polymer 1.0: How to pass an argument to a Polymer function from an attribute?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there a way to pass an argument to a Polymer function from an element attribute inside its `<template>`?

```
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/polymer/polymer.html" />
<dom-module id="example-element">
  <template>
    ...
    <paper-button id="foo" on-tap="bar">Click</paper-button>
    ...
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'example-element',
      properties: {...},
      bar: function(arg){
        // Do stuff using argument arg
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

#### Background Research

I have combed through [the documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview.html) which appears silent on the matter. It doesn't say whether you can or can not. But when I try it, it fails. But maybe I'm not doing it correctly. So I need some assistance.

The only thing I have come across is [event listeners](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html) which doesn't seem to be able to take the arguments I want to pass. Say, an `id` or a `name`.

#### Previous Attempts

I have tried (unsuccessfully) doing things like:

```
<paper-button id="foo" on-tap="bar('foo')"> Click </paper-button>
```

but nothing seems to work.

The event listeners idea doesn't work because they limit the arguments and I can't get the, say, `id` I need.

Comment: An associate says: 

Always a literal string like in your example? You could do something like `on-tap="bar" data-bar="foo"`, then in your event handler, `e.srcElement.getAttribute('data-bar')`.

You can't pass an argument like you tried to do.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could utilize HTML5 data attributes instead. Try like this:

```
<paper-button id="foo" on-tap="bar" data-args="foo,some other value,2">Click</paper-button>
...
<script>
(function() {
  Polymer({
    is: 'example',
    properties: {...},
    bar: function(e){
      var args = e.target.getAttribute('data-args').split(',');
      // now args = ['foo', 'some other value', '2']
    }
  });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, I had to use `Polymer.dom(e).path[2].getAttribute('data-args')`. See here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#retargeting  Answer accepted!

Comment: `e.target.dataset.args` has worked for me and looks a little cleaner.

Comment: @Andrew - you're right. that's a better an cleaner syntax, and considering that I myself wrote HTML5, it's legitimate to use. But in reality, if *not* using the `dataset` property and doing it the way I did, you get better backward compatibility.

Comment: What is the argument is from property, as: data-args="{{some_prop}}", upper solutions are not working. Any idea? (ping @Amit @Mowzer)

Comment: founded, should  be: data-args$="{{some_prop}}" https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding

Comment: I used e.target.dataArgs and worked (maybe a more recent version?)

Answer (score 46):

After searching a lot, I found what I think is the cleanest possible solution.

If the paper-button is inside a template, e.g.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{allItems}}" as="item">
 <paper-button on-tap="itemTapped">[[item.text]]</paper-button>
</template>
```

Then the properties can be accessed via "model" property in event object passed to function.

```
itemTapped: function(oEvent){
// oEvent.model.get is the getter for all properties of "item" in your bound array
console.log(oEvent.model.get('item.task'));
}
```

Comment: Actually this is the correct answer using Polymer 1.7.0 APIs, the previous answer is now obsolete

Comment: With the speed this framework is progressing, stack overflow can be misleading at times :).

Comment: I think that holds true for every framework... For all it counts, I'll be active here, answering as many questions I encounter while developing since I'm working on Polymer for my weekend projects now ...

Comment: In `item.task`, what does `task` signify? Couldn't find it in the template mentioned above.

Comment: This is actually the correct version for Polymer >= 1.x
So, this one should be marked as correct, according to Polymer docs

Comment: It worked for me... and I think perhaps the best approach.

Comment: This looks really linked to the dom-repeat feature only: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#handling-events

Answer (score 10):

Shining more light on a subtle difference mentioned in the comments above.

Notice `$=` must be used if reading a data binding.

```
<paper-button on-tap="_handleTap" data-foo="foo" data-bar$="[[bar]]">Tap</paper-button>

...

_handleTap: function(e) {
  var foo = e.target.dataset.foo;
  var bar = e.target.dataset.bar;
}
```

Inside `dom-repeat`, the `item` (or whichever name you give it) is available at `e.model.item`.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]" as="someItem">
  <paper-button on-tap="_handleTap">Tap</paper-button>
</template>

...

_handleTap: function(e) {
  var item = e.model.someItem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a way to pass an argument to a Polymer function from an attribute of an element inside its `<template>`.

Instead of using an **event** use a **[computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#literals)**.  Computed bindings can accept literal strings.

Checkout the working example below.  In this example a button can be hidden based on the parameter that is passed.

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/polymer/polymer.html" />
<dom-module id="example-element">
 <template>
  <button id="foo-one" on-tap="barEvent">Click foo-one</button>
  <button id="foo-two" hidden="{{barTest('value-two')}}">Click foo-two</button>
  <button id="foo-three" hidden="{{barTest('value-three')}}">Click foo-three</button>
 </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
 Polymer({
  is: "example-element",
  barEvent: function (event) {
   console.log(event.target.id);
  },
  barTest: function (arg) {
   if (arg === "value-two") {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  }
 });
</script>

<example-element></example-element>
```

Note: You can get the `id` or other attributes of an element that an event is run on through `event.target`.  If you are only looking for other attributes as parameters this might also be a valid solution.

Comment: Hmm... this should be the right answer. Simple and clear.

Answer (score 1):

After trying the solutions suggested here which none of them worked, I did a slight modification of @Amit and @Mowzer solutions I got it working like this:

```
<dom-module id="dial-buttons">

    <template>
        <div on-click="handleClick" data-args="0, num-input">
            <p>0</p>
            <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'dial-buttons',
            properties: { ... },
            handleClick: function(e) {
                var args = Polymer.dom(e).path[1].getAttribute('data-args').split(',');
                alert(args[0] + args[1]);
            }
        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just now I got this to work:

```
<paper-button id="foo" on-tap="bar" data-args="baz,qux,quux">Click</paper-button>
...
<script>
(function() {
  Polymer({
    is: 'example',
    properties: {...},
    bar: function(e){
      var args = e.target.dataset.args.split(','); // ['baz', 'qux', 'quux']
    }
  });
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the most robust way to retrieve the argument is as follows:

```
<paper-button on-tap="_getArgs"
              data-args="foo,bar,qux">Click</paper-button>
...
_getArgs: function(e) {
  var args = Polymer.dom(e).rootTarget.getAttribute('data-args');
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, the clean way to do this is usually using [dom-repeat](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates). If you can format your data as an array of objects, you can just use e.model to get everything.