# Polymer 1.0: What native methods are available to event targets?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

[This documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#retargeting) describes Polymer's event retargeting.

Following the documentation, I have obtained a "normalized event object" (NEO) using `Polymer.dom(event)`.

Neither the [event retargeting documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#retargeting) nor the [API documentation](http://polymer.github.io/polymer/) describes what native methods are available (like `.getAttribute()`). For an example, see Amit's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441401/polymer-1-0-is-there-a-way-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-polymer-function-from-an-at).

What native methods are available to this normalized event object? And where are they documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normalized event object has only three properties listed: `rootTarget`, `localTarget`, and `path`. The first two are element/node objects while `path` is an array of nodes at which the event passes through. Your little snippet above would likely be solved by using either of the first two, but I'd suggest using `localTarget` instead since it's the retargeted one.

```
var obj = Polymer.dom(event).localTarget;
var arg = obj.getAttribute('data-foo'); // or obj.dataset.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-api) on the DOM API that contains at least a partial list.

It includes the following.

> ```
> Polymer.dom(parent).appendChild(node)
> Polymer.dom(parent).insertBefore(node, beforeNode)
> Polymer.dom(parent).removeChild(node)
> Polymer.dom.flush()
> Polymer.dom(parent).childNodes
> Polymer.dom(node).parentNode
> Polymer.dom(node).firstChild
> Polymer.dom(node).lastChild
> Polymer.dom(node).firstElementChild
> Polymer.dom(node).lastElementChild
> Polymer.dom(node).previousSibling
> Polymer.dom(node).nextSibling
> Polymer.dom(node).textContent
> Polymer.dom(node).innerHTML
> Polymer.dom(parent).querySelector(selector)
> Polymer.dom(parent).querySelectorAll(selector)
> Polymer.dom(contentElement).getDistributedNodes()
> Polymer.dom(node).getDestinationInsertionPoints()
> Polymer.dom(node).setAttribute(attribute, value)
> Polymer.dom(node).removeAttribute(attribute)
> Polymer.dom(node).classList
> ```