# polymer v 1.0 .. pass values in annotated event handlers

Tags: javascript, polymer

I was wondering how can I pass values to an event handler , when annotating them to an element in a template.

this works:

```
 <button on-click="handleClick">
```

but this doesn't

```
<button on-click on-click="handleClick(someValue)">
```

is there a way?

Comment: added an extra on-click by mistake in the second tag .. please ignore!

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Polymer 1.0. What are you trying to achieve? What is someValue and where is it defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's not totally clear what you are trying to accomplish. So you might want to clarify it a bit. But taking a guess, it sounds like I might still be able to help you...*

Look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441401/polymer-1-0-is-there-a-way-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-polymer-function-from-an-at), the accepted answer and my comment.

[Amit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3887516/amit) points out you could use HTML5 custom (`data-`) attributes. Like this:

```
<paper-button id="foo" on-tap="bar" data-args="foo,some other value,2">Click</paper-button>
...
<script>
(function() {
  Polymer({
    is: 'example',
    properties: {...},
    bar: function(e){
      var args = e.target.getAttribute('data-args').split(',');
      // now args = ['foo', 'some other value', '2']
    }
  });
})();
</script>
```

Which worked for me. However, in my particular use case, I had to use: `Polymer.dom(e).path[2].getAttribute('data-args')`.

To learn more, you can read [this reference on Event Retargeting](http://polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#retargeting).

Comment: yeah.. this would help. Thank you :)

Comment: I just successfully used:
`Polymer.dom(e).rootTarget.getAttribute('data-arg');`

Comment: looks like both Polymer.dom(e).path[2] and rootTarget - may randomly fail because of ripple effect being added/removed to the button. The only stable way I found was localTarget. And to be completely cool you coul use dataset: Polymer.dom(e).localTarget.dataset["args"];

Answer (score 0):

If the handler is scoped inside of the host element you can
add a custom property to the element and supply an argument in
the attribute that binds to that property. You will only be able
to supply one argument to the property, you can use an object.
However it is possible to handle the Annotated Events outside of
the host element structure and this will mean something else.
Using the event that was passed in works always. With a reference
to the element itself you will also be able to access these properties
and bindings as well as the attributes.

```
<dom-module id="awesome-element">
    <template>
        <h1>Awesome Element</h1>
        <content></content>
    </template>
    <script>
        polymer({
            is:'awesome-element',
            properties{
                onearg: {
                    type: String,
                    value: ''
                },
                handleClick: function(e){
                    console.log(this.onearg);

                }
            }
        });
    </script>
<dom-module>
```