# How to pass a parameter to a function in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to call a function and pass a parameter but it gives error that function is not defined. I suppose it's not the proper way to pass argument.

```js
//it's a big component with many methods

updateData: function(id) {
  console.log(id);
  }
```

```html
<div class="basic">
  <preview-list class="profileList">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ followers }}">
      <preview-profile profile$="{{ item }}">
        <div class="connectWrapper">
          <template is="dom-if" if="{_computeIsNotConnected(item.isConnection, item.isConnection2)}}">
            <custom-button on-tap="[[updateData(item.id)]]"></custom-button>
          </template>
        </div>
      </preview-profile>
    </template>
  </preview-list>
</div>
```

It shows the following error :
`` listener method `[[updateData(item.id)]]` not defined ``
I tried with curly braces too.
How could I pass parameter to a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the name of your function and get your object from event parameter:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ data }}">
  <custom-button on-tap="updateData"></custom-button>
</template>
```

And define your event handler like this:

```
updateData: function(event) {
  console.log(event.model.item.id);
}
```

**Update**

as you are  using dom-if inside dom-repeat, it's a bug (https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2574)

you can either use **hidden$="{{_computeIsNotConnected(item.isConnection, item.isConnection2)}}"** instead of dom-if template,

Or use this code snippet instead:

```
<template id="repeater" is="dom-repeat" items="{{ data }}">
  <custom-button on-tap="updateData"></custom-button>
</template>

updateData: function(event) {
  console.log(this.$.repeater.modelForElement(event.target));
}
```

Comment: I dont't have `item` in event.model. I have `e.model.__data__` property but it has all items not currently clicked.

Comment: Which version of polymer are you using? is it 1.0?

Comment: do you use "as" in your dom-repeat?

Comment: No, as `item` is default I know.

Comment: This `custom-element` is wrapped in another element if it is important. I'll add in it my question.

Comment: I have forgotten to add the inner `template is="dom-if"` in my question. This causes the problem. If I remove it, it works fine but how could I use it?

Answer (score 1):

Polymer doesn't want you to pass an argument here. Instead you should access the data you need via the model... `e.model.get('item.id')`. See this answer for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40205828/2718998

Comment: Thank you for these useful links and comments. Maybe I just miss something.