# Polymer 2 event on-change with inputs parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to attach events in a select trought a function in a polymer element.

Till now, what I can do is something like that

html

```
<select on-change="changeData">
        <option>a</option>
..............
```

js

```
  changeData(dataset){
    console.log(dataset.target.value);
  }
```

and it's ok

however, when I want to call a function with inputs parameters I can't

html

```
<select on-change="changeData(event.target.value)">
        <option>a</option>
..............
```

js

```
  changeData(dataset){
    console.log(dataset);
  }
```

It doesn't work. Is anyone able to correct me or at least guide me on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you're registering event handlers in your HTML. Don't do that and you should be good.

Comment: You can only specify a function name in `on-(event)` attributes. The function will always be called with an `event` type object. Give your `<select>` an id and query the selected option in JS. Or use `<iron-selector>`.

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong, the first version is the way to go. What don't you like about it?

Answer (score 0):

As @crazypeter said in the comments, you can't directly pass any arguments when adding event listeners, just the name of the function.

In this case you don't need to (the first example is correct), but if you would you can use data atributtes ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441401/polymer-1-0-is-there-a-way-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-polymer-function-from-an-at)).

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events#annotated-listeners