# These 2 function definitions have different behavior

Tags: javascript, function

Can someone explain why these 2 functions behave differently.

**Snippet 1:**

```
function operate1(operator) {
  return function(x, y) {
    return x + operator + y;
  }
}
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
function operate2(operator) {
  return new Function("x", "y", "return x " + operator + " y;");
}
```

**Usage:**

```
adder1 = operate1("+");
adder2 = operate2("+");

adder1(5, 3);    // returns "5+3"
adder2(5, 3);    // returns 8
```

I am particularly curious of why `operate2` evaluated the arithmetic expression when I thought it would evaluate it as a string at first glance. Does this have something to do with it being defined as a Function Object with the new operator?

Comment: Because `return x + operator + y;` is concatenating the operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first does string concatenation due to the operator being a string

```
return x + "+" + y;
```

The second performs an evaluation of the content because that is how [new Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) works - the result is similar to [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) but have a look at the differences here: [Are eval() and new Function() the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/are-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing)

So the statement

```
new Function("x", "y", "return x " + operator + " y;");
```

has the `"return x " + operator + " y;"` part evaluated

Here is the second version behaving like the first

```js
function operate2(operator) {
  return new Function("x", "y", "return x +'" + operator + "'+ y;");
}
var adder2 = operate2("+");
alert(adder2(5, 3))
```

Comment: Isn't it the same for the second one as well? It should have evaluated as "return x " + "+" + " y;" where "+" is a string too.

Comment: No, `new Function()` has the almost the same functionality as eval under the hood

Comment: is there a documentation that supports your statement that it performs eval on the last argument?

Comment: Have a look at the link I gave. It is not performing an eval, but the string is evaluated

Comment: I updated the answer to include the string version in adder2

Answer (score 1):

It's following the exact description in this documentation on the Mozilla site: [Function - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

The constructor signature:

```
new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)
```

`functionBody` is to be a string containing the JavaScript statements comprising the function definition.

---

What if you actually wanted `adder2` to return a string? This would do it:here's some code that constructs code that generates the expression.

```
function operate2(operator) {
  return new Function("x", "y", "return '' + x + '" + operator + "' + y;");
}
```

Comment: @krato - Please try again - I've gotten it to work:  http://jsfiddle.net/2g9axxhs/