# Build object where the constructor is a string

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Is there a way (except using `eval()`) to build a sapui5 control if the constructor is a string?

For example, I want to build a text control:

```
var oText = new sap.m.Text({});
```

but the part "`new sap.m.Text({})`" is actually a string.
I tried `eval()`:

```
var sObj = "new sap.m.Text({});";
var oObj = eval(sObj);
oObj.setText("Hello");
```

and it works.

The question is if there is another, more secure way to do it.

Comment: @dfsq could you please explain how `new Function` differs from `eval()`?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/are-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @dfsq's comment you can use `new Function`:

```
var fControlGenerator = function (sControlCommand) {
    return new Function("return " + sControlCommand)();
};
var oControl = fControlGenerator("new sap.m.Text()");
```

Comment: You had posted your answer while I was typing mine, which is almost the same as yours. You just saved me some time, good sir!