# Create SAPUI5 control using new Function() and string

Tags: javascript, sapui5

This question is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164480/build-object-where-the-constructor-is-a-string) one.

I have a list of SAPUI5 controls in string format and to extract the required control I use:

```
var sDefaultControlConstructor = "new sap.m.Input()"; 
var sConstructor = "return " + sDefaultControlConstructor;
var oConstructor = new Function(sConstructor);
var oField = oConstructor();
```

The `oField` object I get looks like follows in the console:

> M.c…s.f {bAllowTextSelection: true, mEventRegistry: Object, sId: "id",
>   mProperties: d, mAggregations: Object…}

The problem is that I cannot get the created object using `sap.ui.getCore().byId()` function.

I looked for the differences between the object I create and the object which is created "normally"

```
var oField = new sap.m.Input();
```

it looks like this:

> d {bAllowTextSelection: true, mEventRegistry: Object, sId: "id",
>   mProperties: d, mAggregations: Object…}

Obviously, these two object are different.

The question is how do I create the control of the second format using `new Function()`.

Thank you.

Comment: When I execute your code in the console, it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have found the solution.
I was declaring the control wrong - the id to every control is given by user when this control is being created, while when user doesn't give any id to the control, it is given automatically.

So, when I did

```
var sDefaultControlConstructor = "new sap.m.Input()"; 
var sConstructor = "return " + sDefaultControlConstructor;
var oConstructor = new Function(sConstructor);
var oField = oConstructor();
```

my control `oField` was created with automatically generated and assigned id.

And when I give id to this control afterwards -

```
oField.sId = "someID";
```

this control cannot be seen by `sap.ui.getCore().byId("someID");` (I honestly don't know why. It always return `undefined`).

To fix the issue, its required to assign control's id during the control's creation:

```
var oConstructor = new Function("a", "return new sap.m.Input(a)");
var oField = oConstructor({id:'someID'});
```

OR

```
var sId = 'someID';
var oConstructor = new Function("a", "return new sap.m.Input(a)");
var oField = oConstructor({id:sId});
```

[HERE](http://jsbin.com/zekomubome/edit?html,output) is JSBIN example of two above declarations (working and not working ones).