# Convert array as string to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a `string` variable **`songs`**, with the following content from a streaming log file:

```
[{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/0TLAptKgYxe7F0KewWH6X6','title':'I Need A Forest Fire','album':'The Colour In Anything','artist':'James Blake, Bon Iver','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/7b8f132a8a91d46cce43b42bd0916f16708c8358','date':'May 21, 2016 at 04:41PM'}, 
{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/3cBV8V9zlYNraydyF8NpBY','title':'Dress','album':'Sylvan Esso','artist':'Sylvan Esso','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/d64189ee29314326a188f1a334dfd20c085dfb7e','date':'May 22, 2016 at 06:53PM'}, 
{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/6W3CjUdc26sI1Y7cmelM5A','title':'Stutter','album':'Good Future','artist':'EMEFE','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/10669383f3ca6f90b6692e2da9b6601f020078ff','date':'May 23, 2016 at 12:57AM'}, 
{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/1GxNPd5r7D1zChEMuMhue0','title':'Only','album':'Dawn','artist':'RY X','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/281bc0be895562e7146b361931330ec5a586d1ba','date':'May 24, 2016 at 01:55AM'}]
```

How do I convert it to an actual array in JavaScript? I tried `JSON.parse()` but it failed. Is it because the values are in single-quotes and not double-quotes? (I don't have control over the streaming data file.)

Comment: replace single quotes with double quotes (`str.replace(/'/g, '"')`) and then try JSON.parse

Comment: *`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( <Your string> ));`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)**

```js
var songs = `[{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/0TLAptKgYxe7F0KewWH6X6','title':'I Need A Forest Fire','album':'The Colour In Anything','artist':'James Blake, Bon Iver','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/7b8f132a8a91d46cce43b42bd0916f16708c8358','date':'May 21, 2016 at 04:41PM'}, 
{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/3cBV8V9zlYNraydyF8NpBY','title':'Dress','album':'Sylvan Esso','artist':'Sylvan Esso','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/d64189ee29314326a188f1a334dfd20c085dfb7e','date':'May 22, 2016 at 06:53PM'}, 
{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/6W3CjUdc26sI1Y7cmelM5A','title':'Stutter','album':'Good Future','artist':'EMEFE','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/10669383f3ca6f90b6692e2da9b6601f020078ff','date':'May 23, 2016 at 12:57AM'}, 
{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/1GxNPd5r7D1zChEMuMhue0','title':'Only','album':'Dawn','artist':'RY X','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/281bc0be895562e7146b361931330ec5a586d1ba','date':'May 24, 2016 at 01:55AM'}]`;

var res = eval(songs);

console.log(res);
```

Refer the following question : [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

---

Or replace all single quote with double and then parse it using **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**

```js
var songs = `[{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/0TLAptKgYxe7F0KewWH6X6','title':'I Need A Forest Fire','album':'The Colour In Anything','artist':'James Blake, Bon Iver','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/7b8f132a8a91d46cce43b42bd0916f16708c8358','date':'May 21, 2016 at 04:41PM'}, 
{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/3cBV8V9zlYNraydyF8NpBY','title':'Dress','album':'Sylvan Esso','artist':'Sylvan Esso','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/d64189ee29314326a188f1a334dfd20c085dfb7e','date':'May 22, 2016 at 06:53PM'}, 
{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/6W3CjUdc26sI1Y7cmelM5A','title':'Stutter','album':'Good Future','artist':'EMEFE','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/10669383f3ca6f90b6692e2da9b6601f020078ff','date':'May 23, 2016 at 12:57AM'}, 
{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/1GxNPd5r7D1zChEMuMhue0','title':'Only','album':'Dawn','artist':'RY X','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/281bc0be895562e7146b361931330ec5a586d1ba','date':'May 24, 2016 at 01:55AM'}]`;

var res = JSON.parse(songs.replace(/'/g, '"'));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript `eval` will do the work.

```
var str = "[{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/0TLAptKgYxe7F0KewWH6X6','title':'I Need A Forest Fire','album':'The Colour In Anything','artist':'James Blake, Bon Iver','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/7b8f132a8a91d46cce43b42bd0916f16708c8358','date':'May 21, 2016 at 04:41PM'},{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/3cBV8V9zlYNraydyF8NpBY','title':'Dress','album':'Sylvan Esso','artist':'Sylvan Esso','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/d64189ee29314326a188f1a334dfd20c085dfb7e','date':'May 22, 2016 at 06:53PM'},{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/6W3CjUdc26sI1Y7cmelM5A','title':'Stutter','album':'Good Future','artist':'EMEFE','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/10669383f3ca6f90b6692e2da9b6601f020078ff','date':'May 23, 2016 at 12:57AM'},{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/1GxNPd5r7D1zChEMuMhue0','title':'Only','album':'Dawn','artist':'RY X','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/281bc0be895562e7146b361931330ec5a586d1ba','date':'May 24, 2016 at 01:55AM'}]"
eval(str)
```

Another way of doing it

```
var f = new Function('return ' + str );
var arr = f();
```

You can check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/are-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing) for the difference between `eval` and `new Function`

Comment: @AxelH That's a function constructor where the first argument represents the body of the function to be generated. It's kind of an eval() operation in different toilet..

Comment: updated answer with the link to `eval` and `Function` discussion

Answer (score 0):

Replace all single quotes with double and use JSON.parse() like this:

```
var str = "[{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/0TLAptKgYxe7F0KewWH6X6','title':'I Need A Forest \ Fire','album':'The Colour In Anything','artist':'James Blake, Bon\ Iver','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/7b8f132a8a91d46cce43b42bd0916f16708c8358','date':'May 21, 2016 at 04:41PM'}, \
{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/3cBV8V9zlYNraydyF8NpBY','title':'Dress','album':'Sylvan Esso','artist':'Sylvan Esso','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/d64189ee29314326a188f1a334dfd20c085dfb7e','date':'May 22, 2016 at 06:53PM'}, \
{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/6W3CjUdc26sI1Y7cmelM5A','title':'Stutter','album':'Good Future','artist':'EMEFE','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/10669383f3ca6f90b6692e2da9b6601f020078ff','date':'May 23, 2016 at 12:57AM'}, \
{'url':'https://open.spotify.com/track/1GxNPd5r7D1zChEMuMhue0','title':'Only','album':'Dawn','artist':'RY X','coverUrl':'https://i.scdn.co/image/281bc0be895562e7146b361931330ec5a586d1ba','date':'May 24, 2016 at 01:55AM'}]";

str = str.replace(/'/g, '"');
var strJson = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(strJson);
```

Try [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/sv28chem/)