# How to parse special string as JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string as follows:

```
"{'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857'}}"
```

I want to parse this string as JSON.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). What about the `name` property? Is this `'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857'` a single value or it'll be parsed too?

Comment: To check the valid `JSON` use http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Valid JSON must use double quotes, and not single quotes.

Comment: @akinuri `'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857'` is a single value

Comment: Where did this string come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are provided is not valid JSON. There are two options either use **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)** method or make it valid JSON and parse.

Using **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)** method :

```
var obj = eval('(' + "{'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857'}}" + ')');
```

```js
var obj = eval('(' + "{'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857'}}" + ')');

console.log(obj);
```

But I don't prefer **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)** method, refer : [Don't use eval needlessly!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!)

---

Or converting it to valid JSON by replacing single quotes with double quotes:

```
var obj = JSON.parse("{'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857'}}".replace(/'/g,'"'));
```

```js
var obj = JSON.parse("{'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857'}}".replace(/'/g, '"'));

console.log(obj);
```

**FYI :** The above code only works when there is no `'` (single quote) within property name or value otherwise which replaced by `"`. For generating JSON in that case you need to use much complex regex.

---

But it always better to initialize string itself as a valid JSON and parse it using **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** method.

```
{"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"}}
```

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"}}');

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Replace all single quotes (`'`) with double quotes (`"`).

```
 var s={
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"
        }
    }
```

The JavaScript function `JSON.parse(text)` can be used to convert a JSON text into a JavaScript object:

```
 var j=JSON.parse(x);
```

Now the variable j has the JavaScript object.

Comment: How would he replace them?

Comment: How would he manually replace something in a string which came down from the server?

Comment: Well, then put that in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Valid JSON would be:

```
var text = '{"type": "name", "properties": {"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

Comment: But his question is how to parse the string he has, not some other string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `eval` and want to avoid formatting the string for `JSON.parse`, you could try:

```
var jsonStr = "{'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857'}}";
var jsonFn = new Function("return "+jsonStr);
var json = jsonFn();
```

Or directly:

```
var json = (new Function("return {'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857'}}"))();
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this over `eval`?

Comment: @torazaburo you can cache functions, you can't cache eval. The scope is separated inside `new Function`, and `eval` is brought into the scope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/are-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing