# How to run on the page typed js

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I'm currently working on a project which requires me to run by the user typed javascript in the form of a string.

I've tried adding an empty `<script>` tag to the html and appending the string (containing the users freshly typed *(after the page was loaded)* javascript) to this script tag but this doesn't work. (since the code inside the script tag will be run immediately after the page is loaded).

So I tried a different approach. I wrapped the js string inside of a function like so:
`function runCode() { userString }`
This is what the string I now append to the empty script tag looks like:
`var code = "function runCode() { "+ userString +" }"`

**However** this still doesn't work. The code (userString) shows up in the script tag according to the chrome dev tools, but trying to run the function causes the following error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: runCode is not defined`

## **Does somebody know how this works? What is the proper way for me to do this?**

**Some background:**

The project I'm working on is an online tool to draw using js. The goal here is to use the [two.js](https://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/) library and link it to a modified textarea. ([codemirror](https://codemirror.net)) Clicking the button will take your typed in code and use it to modify the two.js canvas on the other half of the screen.

This will make it easier to draw using the library, since you don't have to set up all the html, css and js files yourself, but instead you can focus on the code.

**Note:** The js you type into the textarea can by any valid js, so simple things as alerts, or even jQuery lines will work just fine.

Comment: The way to execute user-provided script is `eval(code)`. Be aware that this will execute user-provided scripts.

Comment: Just don't use string but echo `"function runCode() { "+ userString +" }"` on the server to have just `function runCode() { userString }` in script tag.

Comment: There is an other way to do this with `new Function`. You can find the differences with `eval` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/are-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing)

Comment: thanks, but ``new Function`` won't work, since I do need to access local variables. @JeanlucaScaljeri

Comment: You can pass in local variables too: `new Function('a', ' console.log(a)');`  This way you have a bit more control over which variables the code can access

Comment: @jeanluca that's actually very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [eval()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/12k71sw7(v=vs.94).aspx) function.
However be aware that this is by design a HUGE hole of security.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the function existed. I'll accept your answer as soon as the site lets me...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use eval(). Extract the user input from an onclick event and pass it into eval like so:

```
eval(userString)
```