# Convert variable string value to expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to convert a string value to expression so that i can use it in if condition like:

```
var StringVal = '20 > 18 && "yes" == "yes"';

if(StringVal){

    ....
}
```

is it possible to do this, please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) would do it, or most likely the `Function` equivalent.

Comment: yes..but it will not work for `"yes" == "yes"`

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: i am working on some survey app and from web service i am getting: `[[abc]] > 18 && [[xyz]] == "yes"`  [[abc]]  and [[xyz]] stands from previous questions answer and i just replace that [[..]] string to real values and after that i have to check the condition..

Comment: i think eval is working...

Comment: Eval would work but you shouldn't use it. Why can't you store the previous answers?

Comment: yes i stored in localstorage, so that i am able to replace with the real values..but after all that on last i have to run the condition according it

Comment: Suppose real values are:  questID:  abc, Value: 20     questID: xyz, Value: 'No'  and i just replace in `20 > 18  && No == Yes`

Comment: If you have the values, I'm not sure why you can't use assign them to variables: `abcValue > 18 && xyzValue == "yes"`. This is far better than using `eval`.

Comment: If you use `eval` someone could type in `location.href="someothersite.com"` and your script would execute it, causing it to navigate away!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not generally safe to take input from a user source and evaluate it, but you could use [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) evaluation, or [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```js
var StringVal = '20 > 18 && "yes" == "yes"';
if (new Function('return (' + StringVal + ')')()) {
  console.log('ok');
}
```

[Are eval() and new Function() the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/are-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing)

Update: If you could give further information in your question as to why you feel this is necessary along with an example of your actual code, then a safer solution could be suggested.

Further: In `JSON2`, `eval` is used in `JSON.parse`

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L491

but you will also notice that some sanitising is performed before `eval` is called.

Comment: Don't use this method! It is dangerous and unnecessary.

Comment: This answers the OP question and states that it is generally not a safe way to do it, I feel the down-vote is unnecessary.

Comment: It is because the OP shouldn't do it this way. The OP doesn't know the correct way do to it and you're encouraging bad practice.

Comment: No, I'm not encouraging bad practice.

Comment: Be aware this won't recognize syntax errors like `'true);(0'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use function `eval()`

try this:

```
var StringVal = '20 > 18 && "yes" == "yes"';

if(eval(StringVal)){

    ....
}
```

other example:

```
var a = '1==3'
var b = '1==1'

console.log(eval(a));
// false
console.log(eval(b));
// true
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `eval` won't directly parse your text as an expression, e.g.

```
eval('{}'); // undefined
```

That's because `{}` is parsed as a block, not as an object initializer expression.

There are several ways to force it to be parsed as an expression, like nesting inside parentheses, or via a `return` statement. So I would use

```js
function evalExpr(expr) {
  Function("return " + expr + ";");
  return eval("(" + expr + ")");
}
console.log(evalExpr('{}')); // Object {}
try { evalExpr('1),(2') } catch(err) { console.error(err); } // SyntaxError
try { evalExpr('1;2') } catch(err) { console.error(err); } // SyntaxError
```

`eval("(" + expr + ")")` evaluates as an expression, and previously `Function("return " + expr + ";")` checks that the expression does not contain an invalid `)` to escape the wrapping parentheses.