# Nested object properties with dynamic name

Tags: javascript

Context: I'm writing a Redux reducer (although this question is not Redux-specific) for my app's settings, which is a nested object. I want to modify the settings object using property names that are given dynamically.

Example:

```js
const settings = {
  service: {
    username: 'TEST',
    password: ''
  }
}

// Normally this would be passed by Redux, but for the purposes of this exercise it's hardcoded

const settingKey = 'service.username';

console.log(settings[settingKey]); // undefined

console.log(eval(`settings.${settingKey}`)); // works, but bad
```

The only way I can think of accessing the subobject without using eval is using a regex to split the `settingKey` into its component parts:

```
const match = /(.+)\.(.+)/.exec(settingKey);
console.log(settings[match[1]][match[2]];
```

```js
const settings = {
  service: {
      username: 'TEST',
      password: ''
  }
}

const settingKey = 'service.username';

const match = /(.+)\.(.+)/.exec(settingKey);

console.log(settings[match[1]][match[2]]);
```

This works, but

1. It's ugly
2. It doesn't work for more deeply nested objects

Is there a way of accessing a nested object's properties with a dynamic name without using regexes or eval?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
var settings = {service: {username: 'TEST', password: ''}}
var key = "service.username";

function getValue(obj, keys){
  keys.split(".").forEach(function(itm){
    obj = obj[itm];
  });
  return obj;
}

getValue(settings, key); //"TEST"
```

Or you can do it simply using `Array#reduce`,

```
var settings = {service: {username: 'TEST', password: ''}}
var key = "service.username", result = key.split(".").reduce((a,b) => a[b], settings);
console.log(result); // "TEST"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there would be a nicer way, but this will have to do.

Comment: ES6 version: `settingName.split('.').reduce((prev, itm) => prev[itm], settings)`

Comment: @marksomnian We had similar intuitions.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option that doesn't use `eval` and works with nested properties.

```js
var settings = {service: {username: 'TEST', password: ''}}
var key = "service.username";
console.log(Function('setting', 'return settings.' + key)(settings));
```

Comment: I didn't even know you could do this. Seems a bit eval-ly, but still cool.

Comment: Isn't this just `eval()` by another name?

Comment: @nnnnnn [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/are-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing).

Comment: So in other words... yes, they're the same thing for *this* purpose, where the input is in a known format.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just change one bit:

```
const settings = {
  service: {
    username: 'TEST',
    password: ''
  }
}
console.log(settings['service'].username);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The `['service'].username` is not known at runtime (all I have is `service.username`).

Comment: i don't understand you. Can you explain more clearly ??