# Setting nested object properties with dynamic name

Tags: javascript

Coming off my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555942/nested-object-properties-with-dynamic-name) (which was about getting the property), I need to set the value of a nested object member using a dynamic property name.

```js
const settings = {
  service: {
    username: 'foo',
    password: 'bar'
  }
};

const settingName = 'service.username';
const newValue = 'baz';

settings[settingName] = newValue ; // doesn't work
console.log(settings.service.username); // foo
```

The only way I can think of is to use eval:

```
eval(`settings.${settingName} = "${newValue}"`);
```

```js
const settings = {
  service: {
    username: 'foo',
    password: 'bar'
  }
}

const settingName = 'service.username';

const newValue = 'baz';

eval(`settings.${settingName} = "${newValue}"`); // works, but bad

console.log(settings.service.username);
```

But this has problems (for example, the example above assumes the new value is a string). **Is there a way to assign a property of a nested object whose name is not known without using eval?**

Comment: Can't you just use a slightly modified version of the getter function from your other question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below,

```
var settings = {service: {username: 'TEST', password: ''}}
var key = "service.username";

function setValue(obj, keys, val){
  keys.split(".").forEach(function(itm, i, arr){
    if (i == arr.length - 1) obj[itm] = val;
    else obj = obj[itm];
  });
}

setValue(settings, key, "hello");
console.log(settings.service.username); //"hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a follow-up on my previous answer: **yes**.

We can use the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor to create and run code that will set the property by its name, as if it were done with a regular dot property access.

```js
const settings = {
  service: {
    username: 'foo',
    password: 'bar'
  }
};

const settingName = 'service.username';
const newValue = 'baz';

Function('settings', 'value', 'settings.' + settingName + ' = value')(settings, newValue);

console.log(settings.service.username); // "baz"
```

Comment: How is this different from my `eval` example above? (I mean, how is this better than eval?)

Comment: @marksomnian My code works for values of any type (not just strings). If you're unclear about the differences between `eval` and the `Function` constructor, you may want to have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/are-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing