# Convert object string to JS object

Tags: javascript, object

Here is a string:

```
"{aa:function(){},bb:document.body}"
```

JSON.parse doesn't work for this,how to convert it to JS object?

Comment: aa:function(){} , this not json

Comment: eventually `eval`, if you are sure about the content.

Comment: eval doesn't work for it too.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON string

Comment: @FeiSun: Well how are you using `eval`... put your real attempts in your question, don't just say you tried them cause you may have tried them wrong! Also, even if you could convert it, what do you expect to do with it? It won't be assigned to anything that you can reference anyway

Comment: But it's a valid JS object form,it should can be converted to JS object.

Comment: No its not valid - See: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation

I think youre mixing up the things.

Comment: @MarioMurrent: OP didn't say it was valid JSON though...

Comment: @FeiSun Not everything that may look like JSON actually is JSON. Your string contains a **function** and an **object reference**. Both of these are invalid and impossible in valid JSON. JSON is a data notation, not executable code!

Comment: @PeterB: Again... OP never said it was valid JSON! Only said they had tried JSON.parse, which is not the same thing

Comment: Trying to use `JSON.parse` is a (possibly implicit and unaware) assumption that something is JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `eval` with a prepended assingment.

Caveat: [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86513/1447675)

```js
var string = "{aa:function(){},bb:document.body}",
    object;
    
eval('object = ' + string);

console.log(object);
```

Comment: To complete your answer, it can also be achieved with ```var obj = eval('(' + string + ')')```. (Using parantheses so that the object is not parsed as a block)

Answer (score 1):

An option in this case could be to use `new Function()`.

It is less *evil* than `eval()`, and here is an answer with an explanation about their difference:

- [Are eval() and new Function() the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/are-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing)

Stack snippet

```js
var string = "{aa:function(){},bb:document.body}",
    object;
    
object = new Function( 'return (' + string + ')' )();

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to treat the string as a json object:

```js
let str = "{\"aa\":\"function() { console.log('Look mama no hands'); }\",\"bb\":\"document.body\"}";
let obj = JSON.parse(str);
let func = null;
eval("func = "+obj.aa);
func();
```