# Call static JavaScript function in class when its name is a string

Tags: javascript, class

Can I dynamically call a static function with name as a string? After some try it's all i can get :

```
   class Test{
        static Instance(){
          console.log( "Instantiated" );
        };
    };

    Test.Instance();//<-- ok

    var testVar = "Test";

    eval( testVar + ".Instance()" ); // ok but eval is evil!

    window[testVar].Instance();//<-- undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window[testVar].Instance')
```

Comment: Put `Test` in an object (along with any other classes you want to do this with) and then use `that_object[testVar]`.

Comment: check if `window.Test` exists?

Comment: @amit77309, window.Test is undefined.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks! It's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `new Function`

Stack snippet

```js
class Test {
  static Instance() {
    console.log("Instantiated");
  };
};

var testVar = "Test";

var func = function(string) {
  return (new Function('return (' + string + ').Instance()')());
}

func(testVar);
```

---

Here is some reading regarding `new Function` compared with `eval`

- [Are eval() and new Function() the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599857/are-eval-and-new-function-the-same-thing)

Comment: That won't work unless `Test` is a global variable, which according to the question, it isn't.

Comment: ...also, `new Function(...)()` will suffer from *almost* all the same security concerns as `eval`.

Comment: @CrazyTrain How is OP's own `window[testVar].Instance();` say it is _not_ a global variable? And the dupe linked suggests `eval` and _objectify_ it as solutions, and with that in mind, you still think this can't count as an option as well?

Comment: @CrazyTrain Btw, should I assume you also down voted?

Comment: @LGSon, thanks a lot!

Comment: @LGSon: `//<-- undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window[testVar].Instance')` If `Test` was global, there would be no error.

Comment: ...and if `Test` *is* global, then there's no need to use `Function` or `eval`.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Because `class` syntax creates a global that does not add to the `window` object. Boy I sure hate how inconsistent they've made the global object.

Comment: LGSon: Yep, sorry about that. Though @GiuseppeCanale should be aware of the security issues. While it's true that `Function` eval'd code can't access local variables, just globals, it's still evaluating the code, so if the string is insecure, the same threats as `eval` do exist. Putting the classes on an object will avoid the need for runtime dynamic code evaluation.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Agree with that, and both the link I provided along with the dupe serves that purpose.