# How do I determine if a String is an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, typescript

Given a string like `"['chad', 123, ['tankie'], '!!!']"`, I need to return a boolean stating whether this string is a valid array or not.

Am open to most solutions, including regex.

Comment: I shudder to say it, but what about `eval()`?

Comment: Your given string is actually not an array. That would need to have the string `chad` to end in a single quote.

Comment: Are your strings always delimited by single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: A string is always an array - an array of characters. If you mean that the content can be an array, like a JSON array, then you need to define the rules for what makes the contents of a string into something that can be parsed into an array of object(s).

Comment: It would be easier if you only accepted valid JSON (double quotes), using `JSON.parse()`. It would throw an error if not valid, which you could catch to return false. If you need to accept the input you provided as an example, `eval()` would also be easy, but not secure depending on your use case (eg. `"[alert('P0wned!')]"`). Are all the items supposed to have primitive types?

Comment: If it's valid Javascript, you should be able to replace the singlequotes with doublequotes, and parse as JSON etc.

Comment: At minimum you can check if the string starts with a `[` and end with a `]`, then proceed to `eval()`. I don't think you can comprehensively regex for a valid JS array because of all the possible features such as anonymous functions which allow for code execution.

Comment: @adeneo You can but then someone will supply a perfectly valid JS array constructed as `["chad", 123, ['ta"nkie'], '!!!']` as the input and now you've danced your way into an invalid JSON for no reason.

Comment: Do you want to support any possible javascript literal, or just a subset? Like "my arrays always contain single quoted strings and other arrays"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an object is an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to support some subset of the Javascript grammar, you can use regular expressions to remove whitespace and scalar literals and then check if what is remaining matches the nested pattern `[,[,,,],,,]`.

```js
let remove = [
    /\s+/g,
    /'(\\.|[^'])*'/g,
    /"(\\.|[^"])*"/g,
    /\d+/g,
];

let emptyArray = /\[,*\]/g;

function stringIsArray(str) {

    for (let r of remove)
        str = str.replace(r, '');

    if (str[0] !== '[')
        return false;

    while (str.match(emptyArray))
        str = str.replace(emptyArray, '');

    return str.length === 0;
}

console.log(stringIsArray("'abc'"));
console.log(stringIsArray(`['abc', ['def', [123, 456], 'ghi',,],,]`));
console.log(stringIsArray(String.raw`
          ['a"b"c', ["d'e'f", 
     [123, [[   [[["[[[5]]]"]]]]], 456], '\"\'""""',,],,]
`));
```

If you want *all* Javascript grammar to be supported (e.g. arrays that contain objects that contain arrays etc), you need a real parser. I wrote a module called [litr](https://github.com/gebrkn/litr) that does exactly that - evaluate javascript literals, all of them:

```
const litr = require('litr'); // or <script src=litr.js>

myJsObject = litr.parse(myString);
console.log('is Array?', Array.isArray(myJsObject))
```

Basically, it's a thin wrapper around a [PEG.js](https://github.com/pegjs/pegjs) javascript grammar.

Comment: Why did you change your answer?

Comment: This has good elements in it like parsing out the quoted stuff. However, compile-time constant literals might include more than can be matched with just a `\d`. Examples include  floats, exponents, signs, math operative symbols, string catenation, etc.. I guess boolean's true/false as well.

Comment: @x15: see the second part of the answer.

Comment: Yeah I see it. Itss a little hard to look at home grown stuff to do this kind of thing.

Comment: @x15: not sure what you mean by that, anyways, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to support "any" string, you could use `new Function()` as a much safer alternative to `eval()`. <sup><sup>[ [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!) ]</sup></sup>

```js
function stringIsArray(str) {
  try {
    return new Function(`return Array.isArray(${str})`)();
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(stringIsArray("abc"));
console.log(stringIsArray("['chad', 123, ['tankie'], '!!!']"));
```

Comment: How about `['c"h"ad', "1'2'3", 't\\"ankie']` etc?

Comment: @georg I've added an alternative.

Comment: `new Function` and `eval` are basically the same thing. Despite of what that MDN page says, there's no difference between them in security or performance. Of course, both do solve the OP's immediate problem (if they are careful enough).

Comment: @georg Eh, I believe "basically the same thing" is a slight overstatement ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4599946/2026606)), though agreed that both require some forethought as it relates to risk/exploitation. With that said, I do think that an approach like yours - using strictly string manipulation - is OP's best bet.

Answer (score 1):

```
let strtotest = "['chad', 123, ['tankie'], '!!!']"
Array.isArray(eval(strtotest))
```

This will return true if the array is valid.
It will also throw an error if the syntax within the string is incorrect, so you'll have to handle that aswell.

I'd like to point out that **`eval` is a horrible thing that you should never use**, but seeing as the requirement of this question is crazy, I thought this solution is fitting.

Comment: >  but seeing as the requirement of this question is crazy, I thought this solution is fitting.
What do you know about the data that is handled here?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use an eval (for obvious reasons of code injection). Parsing as JSON, what I will be doing, is not the same as an array, of course, but it's the closest you're going to get without the use of `eval()`.

Something you can use is the `JSON.parse` method. Only downside here is that all strings must be delimited with double quotes (`"`) due to the restriction of JSON.

Quick example using the nodejs interpreter:

```
> var arrayString = '["chad", 123, ["tankie"], "!!!"]';
undefined
> JSON.parse(arrayString);
[ 'chad', 123, [ 'tankie' ], '!!!' ]
> var notArrayString = 'asdas!asd1{}1239]1[';
undefined
> JSON.parse(notArrayString);
Thrown:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0
>
```

You could then use the `Array.isArray` method to check whether it is an array.

```
function stringIsArray(str) {
    try {
        return Array.isArray(JSON.parse(str));
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}

stringIsArray('["chad", 123, ["tankie"], "!!!"]'); // returns true
stringIsArray('something else, not an array'); // returns false
```

You could add a `str.replace('\'', '"')` if you don't care about the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's useful for someone else, you could do this too and it's in a few lines. if you define in 'a' the string that you want to analyze

```
a = "['chad', 123, ['tankie'], '!!!']";
Array.isArray( JSON.parse( a.replace(/'/g,'"') ) );
```

this will return true or false