# How do I turn a String structured as an Array into a type Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, typescript, type-conversion

I have a type `String` that looks like `'["123", 123, "testing"]'`.

How do I change that `String` into type `Array`?

Comment: `JSON.parse('["123", 123, "testing"]')`

Comment: If that's the format of your string, then just `JSON.parse` it. However, [*your nearly-identical previous question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883897/how-do-i-determine-if-a-string-is-an-array) showed the array in a different format...

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse`. See example below:

```js
var str = '["123", 123, "testing"]';
var strArray = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(strArray);

for(var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(strArray[i]);
}
```