# Postman - calling function in external JS file - 'x is not defined'

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script, minifiedjs

Other posts have dealt with this question, but I continue to be unable to apply this myself.

I have a Postman pre-script test.

I am trying to call an encryption function defined in 
http://some-server:port/lib/forge/forge.min.js

The code calls the code like this:

```
let pubKey = forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(atob(publicKey));
...
let .... = forge.util.encodeUtf8(data));
let ... = forge.util.encode64(text);
...
```

I tried the `eval` trick, putting the whole code into a variable.

```
var code = pm.collectionVariables.get('forge.min.js');
eval(code);
```

The resulting error was:

> ReferenceError: forge is not defined

The code variable has the whole block of minified Javascript.

Comment: How do you retreive the file `forge.min.js`? Maybe it includes some characters at the beginning or ending that should not be there and is therefore invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `eval`, you can do:

```
(new Function(code))();

console.log(forge);
```

Output in Postman console (you can open it bottom right):

```
{
  aes:{...}
  asn1:{...}
  cipher:{...}
  ...
}
```

**Explanation:** I am not sure why, but I just couldn't get `eval` to work. I suspect that it has to do with global scope of VM Postman is using (there is no `window` like in browsers or `global` like in Node.js but a `pm` global object).

Function constructor acts similar to `eval` function, but encloses it into its own inner scope, so outer variables cannot be accessed. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4599946/2619989).

The syntax is a bit confusing, but put in words, it creates a new function and then calls it. There must an extra pair of parentheses around `new Function(...)` since 'function call' operator (the `()` at the end) binds stronger than the 'new' operator.

Comment: I'll try this.  BTW,  regarding `window`, I tried a tip I saw to write `window = {};`, but that had not helped either.